# [Kotlin/Python]Can I merge two maps so the key of the 3rd map is the value of the 1st map and the value of the 3rd map is the value of the 2nd map?

Tags: python, kotlin

Let's say I have these variables,

`val mapOfNodesToCoordinates = mutableMapOf<String, String>()`

9600030594= "1.3289149_103.9296551", 9600040000="1.3279014_103.928449"

`val mapOfWaysToRoutes = mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()`

-122174 = ["9600030594", "9600040000"]

I want a third map which will be:

-122174 = ["1.3289149_103.9296551", "1.3279014_103.928449"]

Can this be done in kotlin or python?

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can achieve this by:

```
val result = mapOfWaysToRoutes.mapValues { (_, values) -> values.map { mapOfNodesToCoordinates[it] } }
```